# Bootstrap Responsive sticky footer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, footer, responsive, sticky-footer

I've been going in circles for 1 day on a simple footer which stays at the bottom of the page, unfixed.

I've managed to have it at the bottom of a full screen page. However, when I decrease the width of my browser's window to simulate a "responsive display", the footer stays at the same place when I scroll down the page and thus does not flush down.

Here is my html :

```
<html>
<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="row text-center">

<p> Blablabla </p>

</div> <!-- row -->

</div> <!-- container -->

    <div class="footer text-center">
            <p class="small">Alright !</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS :

```
html {
 height: 100%; 
}

body {
  height: 100%; 
  padding-bottom: 30px;           
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}
```

I've tried Bootstrap's column on the footer like this :

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">

    <div class="footer text-center">
            <p class="small">&#169; 2017 Le Point G</p>
        </div>

</div>
```

But this method does not seem to be appropriate as it makes it inconsistent on my different pages as the amount of content differs from one page to another, pushing the footer more or less down.

Any better suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have `position:absolute` just add

`min-height:100%;position:relative;`

to your container or row.

```css
.row {
min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
 html {
 height: 100%; 
}

body {

 
  padding-bottom: 30px;           
}

.footer {
position:absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      
       <style type="text/css">
      

       </style>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        
       </script>
       </head>
       <body>
       
     

<div class="container">

<div class="row text-center" >

<p> Blablabla </p>

</div> <!-- row -->

</div> <!-- container -->

    <div class="footer text-center">
            <p class="small">Alright !</p>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

**Explanation**

The container div has a `min-height:100%` -- this will ensure it stays the full height of the screen even if there is hardly any content. The container div is set to `position:relative;` this allows us to absolutely position elements inside it.
The footer has a set height in px. The footer is absolutely positioned with bottom:0 and this moves it to the bottom of the container div. When there is little content on the page the container div is exactly the height of the browser view-port as it is set to `min-height:100%` and the footer sits at the bottom of the screen. When there is more than a page of content the container div becomes larger and extends down below the bottom of the view-port - the footer is still positioned at the bottom of the container div. The footer is also set to `width:100%;` so it covers the whole page.

Comment: But then if I do that, it does not stay at the bottom in a page when there is not enough content to "push it down".

Comment: You need to give your body a min-width so that even if the content is not long enough the footer stays at the bottom

Comment: How much does this min-width would need to be ?

Comment: You need to use media queries for different screen size..wait i am including a snippet for you a an example

Comment: check the snippet..you can achieve it with slight modifiacation.. add `min-height:100%;
   position:relative;` to your container

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks ! Although I don't fully understand the logic.

Comment: i have added a explanation in my answer check if it make you understand the logic better.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the footer always to be fixed to the bottom of the window, reguardless of the length of the content of the page.

If so, try `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute`

```css
html {
 height: 100%; 
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom:30px;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="row text-center">

<h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<h2>Header Level 2</h2>

<ol>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ol>

<blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote>

<h3>Header Level 3</h3>

<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ul>

<pre><code>
#header h1 a {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
}
</code></pre>

</div> <!-- row -->

</div> <!-- container -->

    <div class="footer text-center">
            <p class="small">Alright !</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I expressed myself unclearly. I do not want it to be fixed, but instead always at the bottom of a page, especially when the width of the window gets reduced, which is what I'm struggling to achieve.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "always at the bottom of a page" if not `fixed`. by page, are you referring to the content or the window?

Answer (score 0):

With Bootstrap3 you can use the class `navbar-fixed-bottom`.
Its not that nice but it works.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>..</head>
<body>....
    <div class="navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <p>Your Text</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Something like that, but with "div" tags - w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_fixed_bottom&stacked=h)

Snippet:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
}

.container {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #6c6c6c;
}

myFooter {
  background-color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px){
  footer {
    position: absoulute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #000 !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <p>Some Text in Container</p>
  </div>
  
  <footer class="myFooter text-center">
    <p>Footer Text - Resize Window</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I don't want the footer to be fixed but always at the bottom of the page, which I achieved to do in desktop page, but not in a mobile page.

Comment: Than you can add something like `@media screen and (min-width: 480px)` as CSS to an class or to footer. There you can add CSS rules like `position: fixed;` to set footer to the bottom of the page.

Comment: I edited my answer. In the snippet i added the `@media ... ` in css. Here you can now just add CSS for setting the footer at bottom and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
</style>    
<!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="page-footer font-small indigo">

      <!-- Footer Links -->
      <div class="container text-center text-md-left">

        <!-- Grid row -->
        <div class="row">

          <!-- Grid column -->
          <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">

            <!-- Links -->
            <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4">Links</h5>

            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Very long link 1</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Very long link 2</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Very long link 3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Very long link 4</a>
              </li>
            </ul>

          </div>
          <!-- Grid column -->

          <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none">

          <!-- Grid column -->
          <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">

            <!-- Links -->
            <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4">Links</h5>

            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Link 1</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Link 2</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Link 3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Link 4</a>
              </li>
            </ul>

          </div>
          <!-- Grid column -->

          <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none">

          <!-- Grid column -->
          <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">

            <!-- Links -->
            <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4">Links</h5>

            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Link 1</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Link 2</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Link 3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Link 4</a>
              </li>
            </ul>

          </div>
          <!-- Grid column -->

          <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none">

          <!-- Grid column -->
          <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto">

            <!-- Links -->
            <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4">Links</h5>

            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Link 1</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Link 2</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Link 3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#!">Link 4</a>
              </li>
            </ul>

          </div>
          <!-- Grid column -->

        </div>
        <!-- Grid row -->

      </div>
      <!-- Footer Links -->

      <!-- Copyright -->
      <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">© 2020 Copyright:
        <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/"> MDBootstrap.com</a>
      </div>
      <!-- Copyright -->

    </footer>
    <!-- Footer -->
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.